# How Do I Use Objective-C (ObjC) with JavaScript for Automation (JXA) to create HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, applescript-objc, javascript-automation

I created a simple http request in the following way:

source: [Getting HTML Source from a URL without a Web Browser](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Using-Objective-C-%28ObjC%29-with-JXA#1-getting-html-source-from-a-url-without-a-web-browser)

```
var urlStr = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
var htmlStr = getHTMLSource(urlStr);
htmlStr.substring(0,200);

function getHTMLSource(pURL) {
  var nsURL     = $.NSURL.URLWithString(pURL);
  var nsHTML    = $.NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(nsURL);
  var nsHTMLStr = $.NSString.alloc.initWithDataEncoding(nsHTML, $.NSUTF8StringEncoding);

  var htmlStr   = ObjC.unwrap(nsHTMLStr);

  return htmlStr;
}
```

**However, how do I create a POST request and set the request header**？

Comment: You will need to use Objective-C's [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession) class methods for this.  Have a peruse of that linked documentation and see what you make of it.  If you have specific questions, reply to this comment, tagging me in it.  When I get my computer back in a few days, I'll draft a rough outline script that will show you how to implement it.

Comment: You didn't respond so I'll hold off writing a script until I hear from you that you're still interested, as it'll take me a bit of time that I don't mind putting towards something that is helpful to someone.